# Genera URL apartir de un SLUG laravel 6

Tags: laravel

Busco ideas, tengo mi tabla usuarios con un SLUG único, requiero que el SLUG se vuelva una URL
unica(Ejemplos: https://midominio.com/slug) y que cuando accedan a ella redirija a un formulario(Sera un formulario de registro de usuarios publico y accesible para cualquier persona), ademas el slug tengo que retornarlo para aplicarlo a un campo en el formulario.

No tengo ideas de como realizarlo

Solo busco sugerencias.

Saludos

Comment: Las preguntas basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas, lee [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que yo hago para eso es que uso una librería llamada `cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable` y la instalas por medio de `composer`:

```
composer require cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable
```

Necesitas crear una migración para agregar una columna llamada `slug` de tipo cadena:

```js
Schema::table('table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('slug')->nullable();
});
```

Después, en el modelo en el que lo necesitas, por ejemplo, Model.php, poner lo siguiente:

```js
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;

class Design extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;
    
    public function sluggable()
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'name', // Aquí defines la columna fuente de donde se basará para crear el slug
            ]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the route key for the model.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug'; 
    }
}
```

Cuando crees un nuevo registro de tu modelo, automáticamente se creará el slug, evitará slug repetidos, removerá caracteres no válidos, creando slugs totalmente únicos, todo automáticamente.

Y por ejemplo, cuando vayas a una ruta como la siguiente:

```
Route::get('/designer/{designer}', 'DesignController@show')->name('show.designer');
```

Mediante, por ejemplo un `href` que tenga lo siguiente:

```
href="{{ route('show.designer',[$designer]) }}" // Se pasa el objeto completo
```

Y de este modo tendrás una URL como la siguiente: `domain.com/designer/issac-lovera`

Y es todo.

Comment: Recordemos que las preguntas basadas en opiniones pueden terminar cerradas